# Nested foreach statements to parse XML

Tags: sql, xml, parsing, powershell

I have xml that looks similar to the following

```
<Settings>
    <CentralOnly>
        <DateLists>
            <DateList Name="name1" ID="1">
                <Date>*-01-01</Date>
                <Date>*-12-25</Date>
                <Date>2007-05-28</Date>
                <Date>2007-09-03</Date>
            </DateList>
            <DateList Name="name2" ID="2">
                <Date>2008-11-11</Date>
                <Date>2008-11-27</Date>
            </DateList>
            <DateList Name="name3" ID="3">
                <Date>2008-03-21</Date>
                <Date>2010-04-02</Date>
            </DateList>
        </DateLists>
    </CentralOnly>
</Settings>
```

The end goal is to put this into a sql server 2008 r2 database. My current mode of doing this (poorly) is with each column being written to a separate text file

```
dateID.txt   |  specificDate.txt
    1        |     *-01-01
    1        |     *-12-25
    1        |     2007-05-28
    1        |     2007-09-03
    2        |     2008-11-11
    2        |     2008-11-27
    3        |     2008-03-21
    2        |     2010-04-02
```

The code below I believe is on the right track to do it in that fashion (it doesn't work yet). But there must be a way I could do this with one file, maybe a csv?

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
[xml]$config = Get-Content c:\path\config.xml
new-item c:\path\dlDays.txt -type file -force
new-item c:\path\dlDLID.txt -type file -force
$xml = $config.settings.DateLists.DateList | % $_.DateList{
    $dateID = $_.id
    $eachDate = $_.date | % $_.date{
        $specificDate = $_.date
        add-content c:\path\dlDays.txt $specificDate
        add-content c:\path\dlDLID.txt $dateID
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to understand the question right, you are trying to extract the date id and specific date from an xml file to then import into SQL Server?

Comment: That is correct. I've been tasked to get the data from the XML into sql somehow. And I'm somewhat familiar with powershell so that seemed to be the best way to do it

Comment: Well, I used powershell to get errors from a response xml file.  It is much easier than using VB.Net or C#.  I can't speak for Ruby or Python.  Let me see what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[#12: Output Objects](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-12)

I played with your XML file and instead of outputting to two files I made an array of objects. Then I just piped those objects to Export-Csv.

```
[xml]$config = Get-Content date.xml
$newdlist = @()
foreach($dlist in $config.Settings.CentralOnly.DateLists.DateList){
    $dateID = $dlist.ID
    foreach($date in $dlist.Date){
        $newdlist += @(New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'ID'=$dateID;'Date'=$date})
    }
}
$newdlist | Export-Csv -Path dat.csv
```

Now if you want to use the $newdlist again you can just import the Csv file with Import-Csv.

```
PS C:\> $data = Import-Csv date.csv
PS C:\> $data

ID                                                          Date
--                                                          ----
1                                                           *-01-01
1                                                           *-12-25
1                                                           2007-05-28
1                                                           2007-09-03
2                                                           2008-11-11
2                                                           2008-11-27
3                                                           2008-03-21
3                                                           2010-04-02
```

I have no idea how to use SQL with powershell but it's easier to use the data now.

```
$data | % {"INSERT '$($_.Date)' INTO 'Id' Where 'Id'='$($_.ID)'"}
```

**MORE**

The CSV file looks like this:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"ID","Date"
"1","*-01-01"
"1","*-12-25"
"1","2007-05-28"
"1","2007-09-03"
"2","2008-11-11"
"2","2008-11-27"
"3","2008-03-21"
"3","2010-04-02"
```

Comment: I will give this a shot. I'm not too concerned about the sql part. I can use the csv importer in sql. It's a matter of getting the data in a form that sql will play well with I'm having the issues

Comment: You need to use -noTypeInformation to exclude the type from the csv file

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used to generate a csv file:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -path "c:\temp\datedata.xml"

$nodes = $xml.Settings.CentralOnly.DateLists.DateList

$array = @()

foreach ($node in $nodes) {

    $id = $node.ID

    foreach ($date in $node.Date) {

        $entry = New-Object PSObject -property @{
            ID = $id
            Date = $date
        }

        $array += $entry
    }

}

$array | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\Temp\data.csv' -Delimiter ',' -noTypeInformation
```

**NOTE:** You need to use -noTypeInformation to exclude the type from the csv file.